# How to use a string to form the name of an existing command?

Tags: macros, strings

In my project, I already have a file containing commands for names of my documents :

```
\newcommand{\docOne}{Title of my first document}
\newcommand{\docTwo}{Title of my second document}
...
```

I've also created a function to obtain the word associated with a number between 1 and 9:

```
\newcommand{\getIntToString}{wrongInput}
\newcommand{\setIntToString}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{One}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{2}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{Two}}{}%
    ...
}
```

(where `\ifthenelse` and `\equal` comes from the [ifthen](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/base/ifthen.pdf) package)

This function produce the desired output, for instance when compiling
`\setIntToString{0}\getIntToString\ \setIntToString{1}\getIntToString`
in the document, I obtain "wrongInput One" in the pdf.

I would like to write a function like the following:

```
\newcommand{\docTitle}[1]{%
    \doc\setIntToString{#1}\getIntToString%
}
```

So that `\doc\setIntToString{#1}\getIntToString` becomes `\docOne` if I write `\docTitle{1}`, `\docTwo` if I write `\docTitle{2}`, etc.

I guess this has something to do with `\csname`, `\expandafter`, `\csuse`, `\@namedef` ... but I don't know how to use them.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\docOne}{Title of my first document}
\newcommand{\docTwo}{Title of my second document}

\newcommand{\getIntToString}{wrongInput}
\newcommand{\setIntToString}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{One}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{2}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{Two}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{3}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{Three}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{4}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{Four}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{5}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{Five}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{6}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{Six}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{7}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{Seven}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{8}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{Eight}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{9}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{Nine}}{}%
}

\newcommand{\docTitle}[1]{%
    \doc\setIntToString{#1}\getIntToString%
}

\begin{document}

\setIntToString{0}\getIntToString\ \setIntToString{1}\getIntToString

%\docTitle{1}, \docTitle{2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need `\csname ... \endcsname`.

Comment: I guess, yes, but how?

Especially that the desired command names already exist...

Comment: See also [How to use a string argument to create a macro name and invoke the resulting macro name? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598479/how-to-use-a-string-argument-to-create-a-macro-name-and-invoke-the-resulting-mac?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\docOne}{Title of my first document}
\newcommand{\docTwo}{Title of my second document}

\newcommand{\getIntToString}{wrongInput}
\newcommand{\setIntToString}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{One}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{2}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{Two}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{3}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{Three}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{4}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{Four}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{5}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{Five}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{6}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{Six}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{7}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{Seven}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{8}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{Eight}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{9}}{\renewcommand{\getIntToString}{Nine}}{}%
}

\newcommand{\docTitle}[1]{%
  \begingroup\setIntToString{#1}%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \csname doc\getIntToString\endcsname
}

\begin{document}

\setIntToString{0}\getIntToString\ \setIntToString{1}\getIntToString

\docTitle{1}, \docTitle{2}               

\end{document}
```

The group ensures that the redefinition of `\getIntToString` is forgotten.

[image]

Much better with higher level functions.

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \apeiron_int_to_string:n
 {
  \int_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {1}{One}
    {2}{Two}
    {3}{Three}
    {4}{Four}
    {5}{Five}
    {6}{Six}
    {7}{Seven}
    {8}{Eight}
    {9}{Nine}
   }
   {WrongInput}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\docTitle}{m}
 {
  \use:c { doc \apeiron_int_to_string:n { #1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\docOne}{Title of my first document}
\newcommand{\docTwo}{Title of my second document}

\newcommand{\docWrongInput}{WRONG}

\begin{document}

\docTitle{1}, \docTitle{2}, \docTitle{42}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the `\name`-macro (see in the example below) you can easily both define and call control-sequence-tokens/macros whose names may also contain digits. These digits then may as well come from the values of counters. Using this technique you are not bound to using digits.

The gist of the `\name`-macro is: It takes material **before** the first following opening brace for its **first argument** and material **nested into** the first following opening brace and the matching closing brace for its **second argument** and applies `\csname..\endcsname` to that second argument while leaving the first argument in place. Hereby the first argument my be empty.

You can do things like
`\name\newcommand{foo}...` → `\newcommand\foo...`
`\name\newcommand{foo}[1]{...}` → `\newcommand\foo[1]{...}`
`\name\global\long\def{foo}...` → `\global\long\def\foo...`
`\name{foo}...` → `\foo...`
`\name\string{foo}...` → `\string\foo...`
`\name\expandafter{foo}...` → `\expandafter\foo...`
`\name\name\expandafter{foo}{bar}` → `\expandafter\foo\bar`
`\name\name\let{foo}={bar}` → `\let\foo=\bar`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\name{}\long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\innername{#1}}%
\newcommand\innername[2]{\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}}%
\newcommand\checkwhethernameundefined{}\name\global\let\checkwhethernameundefined={@ifundefined}%

% let's define the macros \doc1, \doc2, ... , \doc12, and \docWeird:
\name\newcommand{doc1}{Title of my first document}
\name\newcommand{doc2}{Title of my second document}
\name\newcommand{doc3}{Title of my third document}
\name\newcommand{doc4}{Title of my fourth document}
\name\newcommand{doc5}{Title of my fifth document}
\name\newcommand{doc6}{Title of my sixth document}
\name\newcommand{doc7}{Title of my seventh document}
\name\newcommand{doc8}{Title of my eighth document}
\name\newcommand{doc9}{Title of my nineth document}
\name\newcommand{doc10}{Title of my tenth document}
\name\newcommand{doc11}{Title of my eleventh document}
\name\newcommand{doc12}{Title of my twelveth document}
\name\newcommand{docWeird}{Title of my weird document}

% let's define a macro for calling these macros:
\newcommand{\docTitle}[1]{%
  \checkwhethernameundefined{doc#1}{%
    \begingroup
    \def\mytempa{#1}\name{@onelevel@sanitize}\mytempa
    \name{@latex@error}%
         {\string\docTitle{\mytempa} not available:\MessageBreak
          Command \name\string{doc\mytempa} undefined}%
         {Use \string\docTitle\space with number in argument in range from 1 to 12 or with\MessageBreak
          the string "Weird".}%
    \endgroup
  }{%
     \name{doc#1}%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

\noindent
\verb|\docTitle{1}|: \docTitle{1}\\
\verb|\docTitle{2}|: \docTitle{2}\\
\verb|\docTitle{3}|: \docTitle{3}\\
\verb|\docTitle{4}|: \docTitle{4}\\
\verb|\docTitle{5}|: \docTitle{5}\\
\verb|\docTitle{6}|: \docTitle{6}\\
\verb|\docTitle{7}|: \docTitle{7}\\
\verb|\docTitle{8}|: \docTitle{8}\\
\verb|\docTitle{9}|: \docTitle{9}\\
\verb|\docTitle{10}|: \docTitle{10}\\
\verb|\docTitle{11}|: \docTitle{11}\\
%
% You can also obtain the thing depending on the value stored in a count-register/a LaTeX counter:
\newcounter{docnumber}%
\setcounter{docnumber}{12}%
Counter \verb|docnumber|'s current value is: \number\value{docnumber}\\
\verb|\docTitle{\number\value{docnumber}}|: \docTitle{\number\value{docnumber}}\\
%
% You are not bound to numbers:
% You can define and use macros with almost arbitrary strings in their names:
\verb|\docTitle{Weird}|: \docTitle{Weird}\\
%
% This yields an error-message as \doc13 is undefined:
% \verb|\docTitle{13}|: \docTitle{13}\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you insist in control sequences `\docOne`, `\docTwo`, ... instead of `\doc1`, `\doc2`, ... , you can still use the `\name`-macro for creating a generic macro which "maps" from digit sequences to these control-sequences.

In the example below the macro `\map` has the syntax

```
\map{⟨macro-name-part before the string which is to be mapped to another string⟩}%
    {⟨string which is to be mapped to another string⟩}%
    {⟨macro-name-part behind the string which is to be mapped to another string⟩}
```

E.g.,
`\map{Foo}{3}{Bar}`
checks whether a mapping from the string `3` to some other string is defined.
If not so, an error-message is raised.
If so, and if `3` is mapped to the string `Three`, it is checked whether the control-sequence `\FooThreeBar` is defined.
If not so, an error-message is raised.
If so, that control-sequence is called.

The macro `\definemapping{⟨string⟩}{⟨replacement⟩}` is used for defining the mappings.

E.g., for the above to work, you would need to apply the command `\definemapping{3}{Three}%` first.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\name{}\long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\innername{#1}}%
\newcommand\innername[2]{\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}}%
\newcommand\checkwhethernameundefined{}\name\global\let\checkwhethernameundefined={@ifundefined}%

\newcommand*\Mappinglist{}%

\newcommand\map[3]{%
  \checkwhethernameundefined{my-map-phrase-#2}{%
    \begingroup
    \def\mytempa{#2}\name{@onelevel@sanitize}\mytempa
    \name{@latex@error}{%
      Cannot map from string `\mytempa' to textual phrase:\MessageBreak
      Macro \name\string{my-map-phrase-\mytempa} undefined
    }{Mapping is defined for the string(s) \MessageBreak\Mappinglist.\MessageBreak
      You can use \string\definemapping\space for defining more mappings.
    }%
    \endgroup
  }{%
    \checkwhethernameundefined{#1\name{my-map-phrase-#2}#3}{%
      \begingroup
      \def\mytempa{#1}\name{@onelevel@sanitize}\mytempa
      \def\mytempb{#3}\name{@onelevel@sanitize}\mytempb
      \name{@latex@error}{%
        Control sequence \name\string{\mytempa\name{my-map-phrase-#2}\mytempb} undefined%
      }{%
        Seems the control sequence \name\string{\mytempa\name{my-map-phrase-#2}\mytempb} needs to be defined.%
      }%
      \endgroup
    }{%
      \name{#1\name{my-map-phrase-#2}#3}%
    }%
  }%
}%

\newcommand\definemapping[2]{%
  \checkwhethernameundefined{my-map-phrase-#1}{%
    \name\newcommand{my-map-phrase-#1}{#2}%
    \name\name\global\let{my-map-phrase-#1}={my-map-phrase-#1}%
    \ifx\Mappinglist\empty\else\name{g@addto@macro}\Mappinglist{, }\fi
    \begingroup
    \def\mytempa{`#1'}\name{@onelevel@sanitize}\mytempa  
    \name\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter{g@addto@macro}\expandafter\Mappinglist\expandafter{\mytempa}%
  }{%
    \begingroup
    \def\mytempa{#1}\name{@onelevel@sanitize}\mytempa
    \name{@latex@error}{%
      Mapping for string `\mytempa'\space already defined%
    }{%
      Each string can have only one mapping.\MessageBreak
      Mappings are already defined for the following strings:\MessageBreak
      \Mappinglist.%
    }%
    \endgroup
  }%
}%

\definemapping{1}{One}%
%\definemapping{1}{Uno}% <- This will raise an error-message.
\definemapping{2}{Two}%
\definemapping{3}{Three}%
\definemapping{4}{Four}%
\definemapping{5}{Five}%
\definemapping{6}{Six}%
\definemapping{7}{Seven}%
\definemapping{8}{Eight}%
\definemapping{9}{Nine}%
\definemapping{10}{Ten}%
\definemapping{11}{Eleven}%
\definemapping{12}{Twelve}%
\definemapping{13}{Thirteen}%
\definemapping{Weird}{Weird}%

% let's define the macros \docOne, \docTwo, ... , \docTwelve and \docWeird:
\newcommand{\docOne}{Title of my first document}
\newcommand{\docTwo}{Title of my second document}
\newcommand{\docThree}{Title of my third document}
\newcommand{\docFour}{Title of my fourth document}
\newcommand{\docFive}{Title of my fifth document}
\newcommand{\docSix}{Title of my sixth document}
\newcommand{\docSeven}{Title of my seventh document}
\newcommand{\docEight}{Title of my eighth document}
\newcommand{\docNine}{Title of my nineth document}
\newcommand{\docTen}{Title of my tenth document}
\newcommand{\docEleven}{Title of my eleventh document}
\newcommand{\docTwelve}{Title of my twelveth document}
\newcommand{\docWeird}{Title of my weird document}

% let's define a macro for calling these macros:
\newcommand{\docTitle}[1]{\map{doc}{#1}{}}%

\begin{document}

\noindent
\verb|\docTitle{1}|: \docTitle{1}\\
\verb|\docTitle{2}|: \docTitle{2}\\
\verb|\docTitle{3}|: \docTitle{3}\\
\verb|\docTitle{4}|: \docTitle{4}\\
\verb|\docTitle{5}|: \docTitle{5}\\
\verb|\docTitle{6}|: \docTitle{6}\\
\verb|\docTitle{7}|: \docTitle{7}\\
\verb|\docTitle{8}|: \docTitle{8}\\
\verb|\docTitle{9}|: \docTitle{9}\\
\verb|\docTitle{10}|: \docTitle{10}\\
\verb|\docTitle{11}|: \docTitle{11}\\
%
% You can also obtain the thing depending on the value stored in a count-register/a LaTeX counter:
\newcounter{docnumber}%
\setcounter{docnumber}{12}%
Counter \verb|docnumber|'s current value is: \number\value{docnumber}\\
\verb|\docTitle{\number\value{docnumber}}|: \docTitle{\number\value{docnumber}}\\
%
% You are not bound to numbers:
% You can define and use macros with almost arbitrary strings in their names:
\verb|\docTitle{Weird}|: \docTitle{Weird}\\
%
% This yields an error-message as \docThirteen is undefined:
%\verb|\docTitle{13}|: \docTitle{13}\\
%
% This yields an error-message as mapping from 14 to phrase is undefined:
%\verb|\docTitle{14}|: \docTitle{14}\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another common strategy is using macro-names which have roman numerals as parts of their names:

```
\documentclass{article}

% let's define the macros \doci, \docii, ... , \docxii:
\newcommand{\doci}{Title of my first document}
\newcommand{\docii}{Title of my second document}
\newcommand{\dociii}{Title of my third document}
\newcommand{\dociv}{Title of my fourth document}
\newcommand{\docv}{Title of my fifth document}
\newcommand{\docvi}{Title of my sixth document}
\newcommand{\docvii}{Title of my seventh document}
\newcommand{\docviii}{Title of my eighth document}
\newcommand{\docix}{Title of my nineth document}
\newcommand{\docx}{Title of my tenth document}
\newcommand{\docxi}{Title of my eleventh document}
\newcommand{\docxii}{Title of my twelveth document}

% let's define a macro for calling these macros:
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\docTitle}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{doc\romannumeral0#1}{%
    \begingroup
    \def\mytempa{#1}\@onelevel@sanitize\mytempa      
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\mytempb\expandafter{\romannumeral0#1}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\mytempb
    \@latex@error
       {\string\docTitle{\mytempa} not available:\MessageBreak
        Command \expandafter\string\csname doc\mytempb\endcsname\space undefined}%
       {Use \string\docTitle\space with number in argument in range from 1 to 12.}%
    \endgroup
  }{%
     \csname doc\romannumeral0#1\endcsname
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
\verb|\docTitle{1}|: \docTitle{1}\\
\verb|\docTitle{2}|: \docTitle{2}\\
\verb|\docTitle{3}|: \docTitle{3}\\
\verb|\docTitle{4}|: \docTitle{4}\\
\verb|\docTitle{5}|: \docTitle{5}\\
\verb|\docTitle{6}|: \docTitle{6}\\
\verb|\docTitle{7}|: \docTitle{7}\\
\verb|\docTitle{8}|: \docTitle{8}\\
\verb|\docTitle{9}|: \docTitle{9}\\
\verb|\docTitle{10}|: \docTitle{10}\\
\verb|\docTitle{11}|: \docTitle{11}\\
%
% You can also obtain the thing depending on the value stored in a count-register/a LaTeX counter:
\newcounter{docnumber}%
\setcounter{docnumber}{12}%
Counter \verb|docnumber|'s current value is: \number\value{docnumber}\\
\verb|\docTitle{\number\value{docnumber}}|: \docTitle{\number\value{docnumber}}\\
%
% This yields an error-message as \docxiii is undefined:
%\verb|\docTitle{13}|: \docTitle{13}\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: This was very enlightning, thank you very much :)