# How to use a string argument to create a macro name and invoke the resulting macro name?

Tags: macros, strings

I get part of a macro name as an argument. I want to use that to form a complete macro name and invoke it. How can I do that?

Here is a test case to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\typeapple}{fruit}
\newcommand{\typecar}{vehicle}
\newcommand{\typeeagle}{bird}
\newcommand{\printtype}[1]{\type#1} % Help me implement this \printtype macro.
\begin{document}
Type of apple is: \printtype{apple}.

Type of car is: \printtype{car}.

Type of eagle is: \printtype{eagle}.
\end{document}
```

I need to implement `\printtype` macro such that it takes one argument, adds `\type` as a prefix to that argument and then invoke the resulting macro name. For example if we call `\printtype{apple}`, it should add `\type` to `apple` to obtain `\typeapple` and then invoke `\typeapple`.

Can this be done?

Comment: I like to use the `etoolbox` (can be done without it). Have `\printtype` run `\csuse{type#1}`. Note I would not use `\newcommand{\typeapple}{fruit}` but rather use `\DeclareType{apple}{fruit}` and internally it would use `\csdef{ll-#1}{#2}` and then alter `\printtype{apple}` to run `\csuse{ll-#1}`. The `ll-` is to saveguard against `\csdef` overwriting something important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `\csname...\endcsname`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\typeapple}{fruit}
\newcommand{\typecar}{vehicle}
\newcommand{\typeeagle}{bird}
\newcommand{\printtype}[1]{\csname type#1\endcsname} % Help me implement this \printtype macro.
\begin{document}
Type of apple is: \printtype{apple}.

Type of car is: \printtype{car}.

Type of eagle is: \printtype{eagle}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

This method can be expanded for the definitions, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\settype[2]{\expandafter\def\csname type#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand{\printtype}[1]{\csname type#1\endcsname}
\settype{apple}{fruit}
\settype{car}{vehicle}
\settype{eagle}{bird}
\begin{document}
Type of apple is: \printtype{apple}.

Type of car is: \printtype{car}.

Type of eagle is: \printtype{eagle}.
\end{document}
```