# Parameterize call to macro

Tags: macros, tex-core, parameters, reflection

I like to parameterize the call to a macro. Please see the minimal example below. I think it is self-explaining.

Ultimately, I am searching for a way to call a macro by a string (kind of reflection).

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\hello{Hello}

\def\trello{Trello}

\def\test#1{\#1llo}

\begin{document}
        
\test{ha} % should print Hallo
\test{tre % should print Trello
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want `\def\test#1{\csname #1llo\endcsname}`? (The LaTeX version of this would be `\newcommand*{\test}[1]{\csname #1llo\endcsname}`. This only works if you add a closing brace to `\test{tre` to make it read `\test{tre}`.) `\csname ...\endcsname` allows you to 'build' the name of a macro/control sequence from 'variable input'. Note that `\csname ...\endcsname` will become `\relax` (i.e. basically do nothing) if the control sequence is undefined. It will not raise an error. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39380/35864 might be interesting.

Comment: Another option is to include `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and then you can define `\def\test#1{\csuse{#1llo}}` and `\test{he}` (note that this needs to be `he`, not `ha` as in your MWE) and `\test{tre}` (note that this needs the trailing `}`) will invoke the desired macros.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a string argument to create a macro name and invoke the resulting macro name?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598479/how-to-use-a-string-argument-to-create-a-macro-name-and-invoke-the-resulting-mac)